# $location changes the ? parameter delimiter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I wan't to open the following url from my controller /plant/needs/temperatures?open=temperatures, where the parameter open=temperatures is there to ask the page to open the related popup with the code as follows:

```
$scope.openPageUrl = function (url) {
    closePopover();
    console.log("Open page url "+url);
    $location.path(url);
};

<a ng-click="openPageUrl('/plant/needs/temperatures?open=temperatures')">Click to open</a>
```

Unfortunately, I've got this url #/plant/needs/temperatures%3Fopen=temperatures requested, with the question mark replaced by %3F, preventing the page to open.

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Looks like the string gets encoded on the server side. What kind of server are you using?

Comment: try `$location.path(decodeURIComponent(url));`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you try to get the current path using `$location.path` it will return path without query strings because `$location.path` don't understand them. So that's why it encodes it when appending new path.

You should use [`$location.url`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#url) which won't encode `?`. Because it handles the changes of `.path`, `.search` and `.hash`

```
$location.url(url);
```

Comment: you saved so much pain for me. Thanks a lot.